# Postgres: Find co-occurrences of array elements

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a text array field in postgres we can call `items`. I want to create a query that will tell me how many times each of these items co-occurs with one another.

For an example set of rows:

```
items
-----
{'a', 'c'}
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
{'a', 'c'}
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Here is example output using a `:` to separate the item name and the count of co-occurrences:

```
item|co_occurrences
-------------------
a   |{c:4,b:2}
b   |{a:2,c:2}
c   |{a:4,b:2}
```

The `item` column lists the individual items. The `co_occurences` column is an array of text elements combining the co-occurring item and the count. What query will produce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of generating row ids for the self-join like @MikeOrganek, I'd just `unnest` twice to produce a relation with duplicate tuples:

```
SELECT x AS item, json_object_agg(y, count ORDER BY count DESC) AS co_occurences
FROM (
  SELECT x, y, count(*)
  FROM example, unnest(items) AS x, unnest(items) AS y
  WHERE x <> y
  GROUP BY x, y
) tmp
GROUP BY x;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2TU50tAI))</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to modify this so that the final list of items is ordered by the count descending?

Answer (score 2):

Convert it into normal relational form first.

This code assigns arbitrary row `id` values:

```
with create_ids as (
  select row_number() over (order by items) as id,
         items
    from item_groups
), normalize as (
  select i.id, u.item
    from create_ids i
         cross join lateral unnest(i.items) as u(item)
), correlate as (
  select a.item, b.item as coitem, count(b.item) as occurence_count
    from normalize a
         left join normalize b
           on b.id = a.id and b.item != a.item
   group by a.item, b.item
)fiddle
select item, jsonb_object_agg(coitem, occurence_count) as co_occurences
  from correlate 
 group by item;
```

Working [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U6CgFJ9w)

If the objective does not have to be JSON, then we can construct a string.  This allows ordering the values in the string:

```
with create_ids as (
  select row_number() over (order by items) as id,
         items
    from item_groups
), normalize as (
  select i.id, u.item
    from create_ids i
         cross join lateral unnest(i.items) as u(item)
), correlate as (
  select a.item, b.item as coitem, count(b.item) as occurence_count
    from normalize a
         left join normalize b
           on b.id = a.id and b.item != a.item
   group by a.item, b.item
)
select item, array_agg(coitem||':'||occurence_count order by occurence_count desc) as co_occurences
  from correlate 
 group by item;
```

Updated [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SBxDDYLQ)

Comment: Thanks. I ran it on my data and got the error `field name must not be null`. I was able to recreate the error in this fiddle by adding a new row that just contains a single item https://dbfiddle.uk/TrJBDPEE

Comment: Adding a `having count(b.item) > 0` seems to fix it. I'm also wondering if it's possible to order the keys by `occurrence_count DESC`. It seems `jsonb_object_agg` can take an `ORDER BY` but it has no effect.

Comment: @mhkeller For the first issue, you can change the `left join` to a regular join, but that would exclude items that are not associated.  Example here:  https://dbfiddle.uk/pjy8e8zX  As for the second issue, the order of keys in a json object is not significant, so you cannot exercise control over how they are ordered in the output.

Comment: @mhkeller  On second thought, you never said anything about json.  This returns `text[]` and can preserve ordering:  https://dbfiddle.uk/SBxDDYLQ

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to edit your answer and I'll mark it as accepted?

Comment: @mhkeller Are you looking for [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jkhd2FuE) maybe?